# Emacs Tramp access to AWS SageMaker instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, emacs, amazon-sagemaker, tramp

I do machine learning code development on an AWS SageMaker instance, and would like to make use of Emacs/Tramp<sup>†</sup>. My question: how, if at all, could that be done? I strongly suspect that some knowledge about security protocols / IAM roles, etc., would be important, but I am a mere SageMaker end-user.

A co-worker may be able to assist on some of these questions, but he is way over-subscribed. It is a big ask of him to indulge my personal preferences (however strong), so I start by posing the question, has anybody else has already solved this problem, or are there good starting points for consideration?

Already seen:

- Martin Baillie's [Emacs TRAMP over AWS SSM APIs](https://martin.baillie.id/wrote/emacs-tramp-over-aws-ssm-apis/), which seems light on key details, and may not be applicable for SageMaker environments
- AWS's own [Tutorial: Set Up PyCharm Professional with a Development Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-pycharm.html), which seems to be pretty specific to PyCharm, and which again may not be suitable for SageMaker environments.

<sup>†</sup>Why? Because I have a long lifetime of using emacs key bindings and macros, etc., that improve my efficiency greatly. Why not emacs within a terminal running on a SageMaker instance? That's what I'm doing now, but it leaves out important flexibility compared with a local windowed emacs client; the latter can be as tall or wide as my pixels permit, can have multiple frames simultaneously, wouldn't have as many networking latencies, etc.